# When should you create a subsystem?

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design

I'm looking into system architecture and can't seem to figure out when you should create a subsystem/what deserves its own subsystem.

Common examples I have seen include: `Input` `Database` `Networking` and `User interface` subsystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There cannot be a general guideline for this.

1. Software projects are very diverse. Some are small and don't need any subsystems. Some are huge and consist of hundreds of subsystems that in turn have their own subsubsystems. Not every system has a database or a user interface.
2. There are also many ways to define a “subsystem”. A subsystem could be a separate class, a package, a library, a project, a microservice, or a number of other things. Sometimes it makes sense to organize code into a separate package, sometimes it makes sense to create a completely separate service. Both are a kind of subsystem, but they are on completely different scales.

One useful way to think about subsystems is [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (DDD). That is really not about systems, but about defining your *problem domain*. It then happens that many software projects span different problem domains. DDD suggests that we establish clear conceptual boundaries between those (a *bounded context*). A bounded context is a good candidate for some separate subsystem, but its up to you to decide how this should be represented in your software. This depends a lot on the complexity of that system, on your organization, and on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, this completely covers what I was asking for! Didn't realise my question was that broad so my apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is a general guideline. If you can isolate some part that does not have to know about the remaining part, you should split up your system. Often you will end up with one part serving the other (so you can speak of a subsystem).

The separated parts will likely be more useful, they can be applied in different scenarios. You will have created yourself some building blocks.

It is all about separating responsibilities. You should end up with blocks that only do one thing. Like store data or transport data. Then you will be in good shape, you can change one block or even replace it without breaking (having to do much work to) any of the other blocks.